# Run background agent on network connection availability change

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, background-agent

I have noticed, that some wp8 apps (e-mail app etc.) updates their live tiles immediately when internet connection is available. Is there any way how to achieve same thing without push notifications using event (Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged)? I know that there are Periodic tasks and Resource intensive tasks, but they run only once per 30 minutes.
Background agent downloads small amount of data, and show notification if data are not equal with data from foreground app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way on WP8, how to trigger update of your app Tile when network connection is available again, sorry. You just need to trust the OS that it will start your PeriodicTask on regular basis.